# How to make in overflow the ellipsis to a clickable link?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want that my overflowed text last item (the ellipsis(...)) to be clickable link. Anybody?

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ellipsis.link.html</title>
  <style>
   .box {
      background-color: #ddd;
      width: 250px;
   }
    .box p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula odio ac nisl
dignissim hendrerit. Proin libero arcu, commodo
in aliquam porta, dignissim sodales tortor. Sed
dignissim mi cursus quam sollicitudin, vitae
semper nunc finibus. In id turpis velit. Nullam
finibus lobortis lacus vel egestas. In pretium
dictum ligula quis pulvinar. Aenean id dolor metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec commodo elementum erat blandit blandit.
Cras quis elementum mi.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I have a bit problem. I need a bit help. How do I have to do to make the 3 dots the ellipsis to work as link? I did not find any solution to it, so I need your help. I saw it on different websites but I did not find solution.

Comment: I thought that it is so simple to solve.

Comment: Even if it was you'd still need to do your research and show us what you'd tried.

Comment: position a span absolutely over the top of it - it should always appear in the bottom right corner

Comment: I can not understand the <span> solution. Could you tell me more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out.

```js
$(function () {
 $('.more-content').on('click', function () {
  $('.maindiv').css('height','300px');
    $('.maindiv').css({
          "white-space": "normal",
          "overflow" : "visible"
    });
    $(this).hide();
 });
});
```

```css
.maindiv {
  width: 250px;
  height: 106px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.more-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 88px;
    right: 19px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
}
a{
 text-decoration : none
}
 .box {
      background-color: #ddd;
      width: 250px;
   }
    .box p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```

```html
<h1>Solution 1 </h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula odio ac nisl
dignissim hendrerit. Proin libero arcu, commodo
in aliquam porta, dignissim sodales tortor. Sed
dignissim mi cursus quam sollicitudin, vitae
semper nunc finibus. In id turpis velit. Nullam
finibus lobortis lacus vel egestas. In pretium
dictum ligula quis pulvinar. Aenean id dolor metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec commodo elementum erat blandit blandit.
Cras quis elementum mi.</p>
</div>

 <a class="more-content" href="#">
     ...
 </a>
 <br/>
 <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
 <br/> <br/>
 <br/> <br/>
 <br/> <br/>
  <br/> <br/>
   <br/> <br/>
   <br/>

 <h1>Solution 2 </h1>

 <div class="box">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula odio ac nisl
dignissim hendrerit. Proin libero arcu, commodo
in aliquam porta, dignissim sodales<span><a href="https://www.google.com/">...</a></span>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be great, but the letters and the line is not whole instead fragmented

Comment: Now I see solution2

Comment: if solution 2 helped you then please undo  the  - vote. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but the second solution is just works, because the end of the text is there. I need an solution where the ellipsis is a link, no matter how long the text.